# How to put button right next to selectbox? (Formatting jQuery-Select2)

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2

**Note**, this is not just another "margin-right" post. [Select2](https://select2.github.io) seems to be screwing me over.

I have a form that looks like this:

[image: Form]

And this is what the same formatting looks like with an error — the email address error is formatted correctly.
*Edit: Revisiting this question, it's not clear to me how the second image is related. I think the point was that I could control whether the error message displayed next to or under the form item but not the button. This was years ago at this point so I don't quite remember, but I wanted to add this disclaimer.*

[image: Form2]

Obviously the `New` button should be next to the patient dropdown.

---

**Here's the problem:**
When you tell Select2 to do its job on a `select`, it hides that element and adds several of its own nested elements to replace it. However, any classes you place on the `select` do not get transferred to these generated elements.

I've set `margin-right:100%` for `.select2-container`, which is what handles the spacing. This is to avoid the behavior in the second screenshot. I don't know of any other way to force the error message onto the next line.

If I set `margin-right:0px`, the button goes next to the dropdown, like I want, but then the error message also sits next to it (pictured above).

HTML source for bottom picture: (I'm posting the source for the second picture because it shows both what I want and what I don't want):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Email">Email Address</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Invalid email format" data-val-regex-pattern=".*" data-val-required="The Email Address field is required." id="Email" name="Email" type="email" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[This <s>code</s> markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFX93.png) is directly below that. The select2 stuff doesn't show up in `view-source`, hence the screenshot.

---

**Fix that I'd like to avoid:**
I could set `margin-right:0px`, then wrap the dozens of other select boxes in a `div` that has `margin-right:100%`, but that would be a raging pain in the butt.

---

**Attempted solution that didn't work:**
Setting `margin-left:100%` or `margin-left:600px`, etc on the error class.

---

**Summary:**
I need to put the `New` button directly next to the `Select a patient...` dropdown, but I don't have access to the style for the dropdown.

---

If it makes any difference, I'm using ASP.NET MVC with Bootstrap.

Comment: What about simply wrapping the `<select>` element in a div of sorts? Select2 is quite smart at calculating widths, so if you wrap it in a div that has a certain width (inferred by layout or declared explcitly), it typically will obey that width in the generated replacement DOM element.

Comment: @Terry Good idea that I overlooked. However, I'm running into some weirdness implementing that. I wrapped it in a `div` with `width:280px` and `margin-right:0px` set, but it's still being displayed as if `margin-right` was `100%`. If I open the Chrome dev tools and look at it, Chrome tells me its margin style is being applied, but also [shows that it has a margin](https://i.imgur.com/Wp2TIIK.png). I don't know where that margin is coming from.

Comment: @Sinjai this happens because you have not set the wrapper `div` `display` to `inline-block`. please set that and check.

Comment: @Jithin that did it. Could you post an answer explaining why that works so I can mark it? I don't see why `height` and `width` support is needed here, which, as far as I know, is the only difference between `inline` and `inline-block`.

Comment: @Sinjai I have put answer for you. You if understand my answer and it was helpful for you plz mark as answer and give a up vote.ty

Comment: @Jithin I don't really understand the explanation, but it did solve my problem, so I marked it.

Comment: @Sinjai The main difference is the `line break before or after` -  `inline-block Element` has it and `inline Element` doesn't have it that why the weird behaviour from your error Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `span` is a `inline` element - ***An inline element has no line break before or after it, and it tolerates HTML elements next to it.***

What I did was made it an `inline-block` element - ***An inline-block element is placed as an inline element (on the same line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element***

So as default it will be broken from it's line and align next line properly. If. It's still in the same line. In `inline-block` element we can set `width and height` as in the case of `inline` element it's not possible.

Tip: Always use `inline-block` element for your wrappers for better alignment and wrapping it's children's properly.